# How to store and get image from a image variable (SESSION)?

Tags: php

here is my code, test1.php works, test2.php not works.

test1.php:

```
<?php

session_start();

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

$text = rand(1000,9999);
$font_size = 5;

$image_width = imagefontwidth($font_size) * strlen($text);
$image_height = imagefontheight($font_size);
$image = imagecreate($image_width, $image_height);

imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);

imagestring($image, $font_size, 0, 0, $text, $text_color);

$_SESSION['image'] = $image;

$image_session = $_SESSION['image'];
imagejpeg($image_session);

?>
```

test2.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
$image_session = $_SESSION['image'];
imagejpeg($image_session);

?>
```

As you can see, test1.php create a random image.
I can use:

```
<img src="test1.php">
```

to show the image from test1.php in any pages.
but, I want to use if else statement in other php files.

for example:

if users click submit button and enter nothing(no answer), the image will still the same, they have to answer the same question. if failed, the image will change.

I don't want to use javascript to prevent users input nothing and store images in disk.

so, I think that I need a variable to store the image that can be used again.
but I found I cannot use above method.

how can I achieve this?

Comment: will store work ?
 imagejpeg($image_session, "/home/abc/a.jpg");

Comment: ya, but I don't want to store it, because I will need a folder that can be write into and it can consume too many disk space.

Comment: HD is bigger than RAM as all sessions are usually stored in RAM.

Comment: ya, but why session cannot store image? wrong method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`imagecreate()` returns a *resource* representing given image. PHP's sessions cannot store resource-type variables (more precisely - PHP is unable to serialize them upon script end), see http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php:

> Note: It is currently impossible to register resource variables in a
>   session. ...

You may serialize the image to a string and store this string to the session (not tested):

test1.php:

```
...

ob_start();
imagejpeg($image);
$contents = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$_SESSION['image'] = $contents;
```

test2.php:

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
die($_SESSION['image']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing much about the context, can't you do something like

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['randomValue'] = mt_rand(1000,9999);

if(someValueIsEntered){
     $_SESSION['randomValue'] = mt_rand(1000,9999);
}

echo "<img src='test.php?random=".$_SESSION['randomValue']."'/>";
```

Test.php

```
$randomValue = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'random');

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

$text = $randomValue;
$font_size = 5;

$image_width = imagefontwidth($font_size) * strlen($text);
$image_height = imagefontheight($font_size);
$image = imagecreate($image_width, $image_height);

imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);

imagestring($image, $font_size, 0, 0, $text, $text_color);

imagejpeg($image);
```

**Multiple parameters example:**

Store the information about the image in an array.

```
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['imageData']){
    $_SESSION['imageData'] = array(
                                   "random" => mt_rand(1000,9999),
                                   "x1" => mt_rand(0,10),
                                   "x2" => mt_rand(0,10)
                                   );
}

if(someValueIsEntered){
    //Randomize array again.
}

$imageString = "test.php";
foreach ($_SESSION['imageData'] as $key => $value) {
    $index = current($array);

    if($index == 0) {
       $seperator = "?";
    } else {
       $seperator = "&";
    }

    $imageString .= $seperator.$key."=".$value;
}

echo "<img src='".$imageString."'/>";
```

And just call them in the test.php then.

Comment: thanks, I was using similar method. I use session to store the random number, and transfer it to test1.php. It works, but after I add imageline  into it, I found that I have to pass so many data to it. so I am looking for better way.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. How does this differ in the amount of data passing?

Comment: for example: imageline() function need $x1 $y1 $x2 $y2, then I need to create 4 session vars to save the random values. why I cannot use one session?

Comment: You would using the other approach too. But you can of course just use an array in the session variable. Check my updated answer.